# How can I instal the ES module and see if everything is ok with the Slash Command so that it becomes an interaction?

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js

I would like to know how to solve this problem and how to install the package.

Error message:

> (node:52822) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension. (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

Here is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ 
    intents: [
        Discord.GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        Discord.GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent
]
    });


const data = new SlashCommandBuilder()

    .setName("help")
    .setDescription("pour savoir toutes les commandes utilisables")
    .setName("moderation")
    .setDescription("pour avoir toutes les commandes de moderation")
    .setName("description")
    .setDescription("pour connaître l'histoire d'Athéna")
    .setName("calin")
    .setDescription("donner un câlin à un membre");

    import { ApplicationCommandOptionType } from 'discord.js';

    // No intents are needed for responding to slash commands
    client.on('ready', () => {
        client.application.commands.set([calinCommandData]);
    });

    // Type hint for VSCode Intellisense when writing object
    /** @type {import('discord.js').APIApplicationCommand} */
    const calinCommandData = {
        name: 'calin',
        description: 'donner un calin à un membre',
        options: [
            {
                type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.User,
                name: 'Utilisateur',
                description: 'Utilsateur mentionné',
                required: true
            }
        ]
        };


client.on("ready", async () => {
    
    //client.application.commands.create(data);
    //client.guilds.cache.get("1188889165430005930", "996365273688965170").commands.create(data);

    console.log(client.guilds.cache.get("1188889165430005930","996365273688965170").commands.cache);
    await client.guilds.cache.get("1188889165430005930","996365273688965170").commands.fetch();
    console.log(client.guilds.cache.get("1188889165430005930","996365273688965170").commands.cache);
    
    console.log("bot opérationnel");
});

client.on("messageCreate", message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;
 
    //+help
 if (message.content === prefix + "help"){
    const embed = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor("#ffcc00")
        .setTitle("**__Les commandes du bot__**")
        .setURL("https://discord.js.org/")
        .setDescription("Vous trouverez toutes les commandes dont vous pouvez faire usage")
        .addFields(
            { name: '**__+commandes:__**', value: 'Affiche la liste des commandes' },
            { name: '**__+description:__**', value: 'Affiche la description du bot' },
            { name: '**__+info:__**', value: 'Affiche les informations du bot' },
            { name: '**__Support Developpement:__**', value: 'https://discord.gg/H9mSXeAm8C' }
           
        );
            
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed]});

}
  //+description
  if (message.content === prefix + "description"){
    const embed = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor("#ffcc00")
        .setTitle("**__Description du bot__**")
        .setURL("https://discord.js.org/")
        .setDescription("Je suis Athéna, une déesse grec de l'artisanat et de la stratégie guerrière. Je m'occupe de la modération, jeux et de trackage d’information ");
    
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed]});

}
  

    console.log(message);
    if(message.content === "Salut"){
        message.reply("Bonjour jeune aventurier");
    }
    if(message.content === "salut"){
        message.reply("Bonjour jeune aventurier");
    }
    if(message.content === "Coucou"){
        message.reply("Bonjour jeune aventurier");
    }
    if(message.content === "coucou"){
        message.reply("Bonjour jeune aventurier");
    }
    if(message.content === "Hey"){
        message.reply("Bonjour jeune aventurier");
    }
    if(message.content === "Heyyy"){
        message.reply("Bonjour jeune aventurier");
    }
    if(message.content === "Hey tlm"){
        message.reply("Bonjour jeune aventurier");
    }
    if(message.content === "slt tlm"){
        message.reply("Bonjour jeune aventurier");
    }
    if(message.content === "Slt tlm"){
        message.reply("Bonjour jeune aventurier");
    }
    if(message.content === "hey"){
        message.reply("Bonjour jeune aventurier");
    }
    if(message.content === "Bonjour"){
        message.reply("Bonjour jeune aventurier");
    }
    if(message.content === "bonjour"){
        message.reply("Bonjour jeune aventurier");
    }
    if(message.content === "Bonne nuit"){
        message.reply("Bonne nuit à toi, Héro !");
    }
    if(message.content === "bonne nuit"){
        message.reply("Bonne nuit à toi, Héro !");
    }
    if(message.content === "Bonne nuit tlm"){
        message.reply("Bonne nuit à toi, Héro !");
    }
    else if(message.content === "help"){
        message.channel.send("**__les commandes du bot ATHENA sont__**\n - +help: Il permettra de configurer et de mieux comprendre les commandes")
    }
    else if(message.content === "description"){
        message.channel.send("**__Pour connaître la description du bot ATHENA sont__**\n - +description: Il permettra de connaître l'histoire et la naîssance du bot")
    }
    else if(message.content === "mention"){
        message.reply("Mention d'un utilisateur : <@" + message.author.id + "> \n Mention d'un salon : <#" + message.channel.id + ">");
    }

});

client.on("interactionCreate", interaction => {
    if(interaction.isCommand()){
        if(interaction.commandName === "help"){
            interaction.reply("pour connaître mes commandes de moderation: /moderation");
        }
    }

});

client.on('interactionCreate', interaction => {
    // We only have chat input commands registered
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

    // Get necessary properties from the interaction object
    const { commandName, options } = interaction;

    switch (commandName) {
        case 'calin': {
            // Pass true as the second argument since 'Utilisateur' is a required option
            // user will never be null/undefined
            const user = options.getUser('Utilisateur', true);

            // User objects turn into mentions when inserted into a string
            interaction.reply(`Merci du gros câlin ${user}`);
        } break;
    }
    switch (commandName) {
        case 'calin': {
            const user = options.getUser('Utilisateur', true);
            interaction.reply(`Merci du gros câlin ${user}`);
        } break;
    
        case 'help':
            interaction.reply('pour connaître mes commandes de moderation: /moderation');
            break;
    
        case 'description':
            interaction.reply("Je suis Athéna, une déesse grec de l'artisanat et de la stratégie guerrière. Je m'occupe de la modération, jeux et de trackage d’information");
            break;
    }
});

client.login("MTE4MDkyOTc4MzExMTExMDg0Ng.GiMXU7._4aDQ7C_IYRBTT_gXX_nNCIZ2h4TCF0DzIdzcM")
const prefix = "+"
```

I would like to know what the problem is, how to download the file in the package, and if you can check if everything is ok in my Slash Command? Because for the 'calin' function it's an interaction function to id someone.

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be arising from the package.json file. In order to use the 'required()' way of using a package, you need to set the "type" in the package.json file to "commonjs" instead of "module".

[Insert "type": "commonjs" directly below "main":"" in the package.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTa2p.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).